# "the name '' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using Unity 3d and C# I'm trying to create a button that on .onTouchUpInside
will fire an animation to hide 2 buttons, take a screenshot and show the buttons again. 
The animations and take screenshot methods both work independently. and they work together being able to hide one button.

But when I try putting the secondary button in the method it comes up with

*the name '' does not exist in the current context*

```
var touchable = UIButton.create( "CameraUp.png", "CameraUp.png", 0, 0 );

//touchable.onTouchUpInside += ( sender ) => StartCoroutine( TakeScreenshot(this) );
touchable.onTouchUpInside += ( sender ) => StartCoroutine( hidebuttonani(touchable, info) );
touchable.onTouchUpInside += ( sender ) => Debug.Log( "Camera button pressed " );


var info = UIButton.create ("FacebookIcon.png", "FacebookIcon.png", 0, 0);
var alertTitle = new string[] { "testing" };
info.onTouchUpInside += ( sender ) => EtceteraBinding.showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons( "hi ", "yest ", alertTitle );
```

// UIObjects can be used like panels to be grouped together
    var panel = new UIObject();
    info.parentUIObject = panel;
    touchable.parentUIObject = panel;

```
StartCoroutine( hidebuttonani( panel ) );

}

private IEnumerator hidebuttonani ( UIObject sprite )
//private IEnumerator hidebuttonani (UIButton touchable, UIButton Info)
{

if ( true )
{
var ani = sprite.alphaTo( 0.01f, 0f, Easing.Linear.easeIn );

StartCoroutine( TakeScreenshot(this) );

yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

ani.autoreverse = true;
yield return ani.chain();

ani = sprite.alphaTo( 01f, 0f, Easing.Linear.easeOut );
yield return ani.chain();


ani = sprite.alphaTo( 0.7f, 1.0f, Easing.Linear.easeOut );
yield return ani.chain();
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: 1st where is the error occuring when you debug? Is the button public so its available for the script?

Comment: The error comes on at line 25

  touchable.onTouchUpInside += ( sender ) => StartCoroutine (hidebuttonani (panel) );

Im using Prime31 UIToolkit to try, .onTouchUpInside play an animation to the alpha channel of the button to hide them, take a screenshot, then reappear. I can do it with one button but I cant imput the other button that I need as its not in the same group ' touchble. ) as the other button I need to attach is in the group ' info. '

Comment: I've tried creating a group to group the two buttons together, 
 var panel = new UIObject();
    info.parentUIObject = panel;
    touchable.parentUIObject = panel;
then implement the start Coroutine (hidebuttonani (panel) ); with the command .TouchUpInside under the .touchable, but it says then 
"The name 'panel' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: The outcome for this is I want when you take a photo for the two buttons to disappear and when you click the other button, another action happens instead